# Android Studio: java.io.FileNotFoundException on attempt to play audio after converting string from HashMap to Uri

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm creating a small android app, there's 8 buttons and when you tap one it gives you a french translation of the phrase on the button. I achieve this by applying a tag to each button, and assigning each tag number to a value (the audio file paths) using HashMaps.

My issue is that if I simply hardcode the Uri, it will work. But if I attempt to dynamically refer to the audio file path by getting the value of the associated tag on the button, use that to get the string associated with the key (the Uri), convert that string to Uri, and then attempt to play it using the MediaPlayer, my app crashes.

I've attempted to simplify the names of the files to ensure I wasn't simply overlooking the naming. I've logged/printed the Uri to make sure the formatting of it looked proper. I've messed around with different ways of converting but they all end the same way.

If I replace

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uriPath);
```

with simply

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doyouspeakenglish);
```

then it works, even though printing out uriPath yields the same string.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void speakPhrase(View view)
{
    Button currentButton = (Button) view;

    Integer key = 
    Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(currentButton.getTag()));

    String newSound = map.get(key);
    Uri uriPath = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(newSound));

    System.out.println(uriPath);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uriPath);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map.put(0, "R.raw.doyouspeakenglish");
    map.put(1, "R.raw.goodevening");
    map.put(2, "R.raw.hello");
    map.put(3, "R.raw.howareyou");
    map.put(4, "R.raw.ilivein");
    map.put(5, "R.raw.mynameis");
    map.put(6, "R.raw.please");
    map.put(7, "R.raw.welcome");


}
```

Expected: Play the audio file "doyouspeakenglish" found in the raw resources folder.

Actual: Crash

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open R.raw.doyouspeakenglish: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: R.raw.doyouspeakenglish
D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
    java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1191)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1164)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1082)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1007)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:914)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:891)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:870)
        at com.example.nathan.basicphrases.MainActivity.speakPhrase(MainActivity.java:31)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nathan.basicphrases, PID: 18531
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.nathan.basicphrases.MainActivity.speakPhrase(MainActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18531 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: You seem to be using onClick="methodName()" on your views, that is a very obstuse way to code. Instead you should get the view and associate a OnCLickListener from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by writing the file name itself as the tag and using

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(tag, "raw", getPackageName()));
```

instead.